# Setting SSL termination with DCOS load balancer

Tags: ssl, https, dcos, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to achieve on Azure something similar as ALB on AWS. Where you can assign a certificate to ALB and you can use https. Where SSL is being terminated at load balancer and request is then forwarded to the services as normal http request.

I am running DCOS on azure (I have created it based on the documentation on their site) and I am trying to set up https. I have read many documentations that I can achieve this with Application Gateway, but somehow I am not being able to make it to work. I have chosen:

- `Virtual machine` as Backend pool and set **VIRTUAL MACHINE** as `dcos-master` and **NETWORK INTERFACE** as `dcos-master-nic`, that did not help.

Later I have tried with:

- `VMSS` setting and set **VIRTUAL MACHINE** as `dcos-agent-public` and **NETWORK INTERFACE** as `agentNodeNic`, that did not help as well.

As last resort I have chosen:

- `IP Address or FQDN` setting and there I have set **NAME** as Public IP of `dcos-agent-lb` and that did not help either.

I have checked all the Inbound ports for `master` and `agent` as well.

Anyone have experience with setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to set up an exact scenario - but you should ensure that the health probes sent by Application Gateway return a 200 OK from the dcos-master VM, before traffic can be routed to it. You should look at backend health results page in portal, under Monitroing section, to see the current state of backend servers (healthy, unhealthy etc) and the reason if the backend is shown as unhealthy.

Comment: I did not manage to make it work with Application Gateway so I went for this solution at the moment. It was pretty straight forward and easy to set up: https://github.com/mesosphere/letsencrypt-dcos. It sets up SSL certificate and I can access my services through HTTPS.